# Mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary

Tags: ios, macos, codesign

> Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73844904/lib-not-valid-for-use-in-process-mapped-file-has-no-cdhash-completely-unsign) looks similar, but is **different**. The error here is about a file having no Team ID, whereas the linked answer is about adhoc-signing a file that is not signed at all. The answer there (explaining how to adhoc-sign) does not solve the problem here.

Trying to run an executable linking to a dynamic library, I get the following error:

```
Library not loaded:
[...]
Reason: tried:
    <lib> not valid for use in process: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a 
    platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?))
```

How can I check the signature and fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<lib> not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73844904/lib-not-valid-for-use-in-process-mapped-file-has-no-cdhash-completely-unsign)

Comment: No. It's not the same error, and it is not the same answer. Check the error messages, and check the answers :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the signature of your  file with:

```
% codesign -d -v ./mavsdk
```

It may show, for instance (note in particular the **Signature=adhoc**):

```
Executable=<path/to/lib>
Identifier=some.package.name
Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20400 size=253962 flags=0x2(adhoc) hashes=7930+3 location=embedded
Signature=adhoc
Info.plist entries=11
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=13
Internal requirements count=0 size=12
```

In order to sign the library, first list your identities:

```
% security find-identity -v -p codesigning
```

It may show something like this:

```cpp
  1) D3F12EDB89FF03FEBA39D1A45F8BD300BAC1C3F0 "Apple Development: Your Name (234MBK19TS)"
  2) CA4F82BC3C4BABE180CC8BC52A48CBF4DE0E2CAA "lldb_codesign"
  3) EB4AD59AE2BBD1C8A0F43C9B2AAA7FBDA1B0D3EE "gdb-cert"
     3 valid identities found
```

In which case you can sign the library with:

```
% codesign -s "Apple Development: Your Name (234MBK19TS)" <lib>
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. When tried to sign the library, library was already signed...

```
<lib>: is already signed
```

Forcing the signature solved the issue :

```
% codesign -s "Apple Development: Your Name (234MBK19TS)" -f <lib>
```