# How can I adhoc-sign a library?

Tags: ios, macos, codesign

Trying to run an executable linking to a dynamic library, I get the following error:

```
Library not loaded:
[...]
Reason: tried:
    <lib> not valid for use in process: mapped file has no 
    cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

How can I ad-hoc sign my lib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can confirm that your library is not signed with:

```
% codesign -d -v <lib>
```

Which should say:

```
<lib>: code object is not signed at all
```

Ad-hoc sign it with:

```
% codesign -s - <lib>
```

Comment: after this I have another error: code signing blocked mmap()

Answer (score 6):

Although not advised for a production system, you can bypass the checks with these two build flags.

See Xcode project target settings, Signing and Capabilities,
then clean and rebuild

[image: XCODE Signing and Capabilities]

Comment: It would be nice to be able to fix the problem though.